# VMWare ESXi 4.1.0 - Checking SMART info

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, smart

I'd like to know if there's a way to check the SMART info for hard drives on VMWare ESXi 4.1.0? Thank you.

Comment: why are you on such an old version?

Answer (score 1):

Access to SMART info  was not introduced until 5.1.

See KB article here:http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2040405